# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected for select to_char(to_date('03/09/1982','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DY')

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I tried to implement

```
select to_char(to_date('03/09/1982','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DY')
```

but its showing me

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

I am working on `oracle 10g express` edition.

Comment: Do you want to assign the result into a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, there is no `SELECT` without `FROM`.  You can use the `dual` table for this purpose:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/09/1982','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DY')
FROM dual
```